# Why friction as a method of charging is used only for insulators not for conductors?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electrons, charge

I was solving a question of electrostatics and it was *Friction as a method of charging is used for whom ?* I answered both insulator and conductor because friction causes production of heat which in turn causes loss of electrons from one body which are then gained by other body but answer was insulators only. Why is my logic wrong ?

Comment: Why do you think that the production of heat causes the loss of electrons?

Comment: FYI: The dry, academic name for "friction as a method of charging" is [_triboelectricity_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect). Maybe that can help you with your search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because insulating materials do not allow electrons to move freely about on their surfaces, it is possible to "stick" electrons onto an insulating surface and have them stay put there. This is not possible with conductive surfaces, because the electrons can flow away from each other when they detect other electrons being "crowded in".